# How to move contacts from SIM to phone - need simple "private" local storage app

Tags: contacts, sim-card

I've read like these posts:
[How to move contacts from SIM to phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/29902/how-to-move-contacts-from-sim-to-phone)

However, my Alcatel Android 4.4 phone does not have contacts app as purchased, only some People app that can display and group contacts, no other actions as I see.

Please advice on simple app to copy/move contacts from/to SIM that is not trying to ask for permissions I don't see it needs, like internet, sms, calls, etc. Ads ok (don't think ads work w/out internet though) :-)

Thanks a lot!

P.S. I've tried to extract Contacts app from other phone, but PC app that extracted some apk-s failed to do that, as I see it, when functionality is part of initial install package, there is no apk file on device.